# $\sum a_n^3$ converges implies that $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $\sum a_n^3$ converges implies that $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges?

I guess it is wrong, since we do not assume $a_n\geq 0$. But how to find an example?

Clearly, $a_n$ should be sign-alternating, but such kind of $(-1)^n/n^{1/3}$ does not help.

Comment: Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: Why is this so obviously true if $a_n$ are all $>0?$

Comment: @AdamRubinson Hölder's inequality.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Holder's inequality, but let me try. $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k\cdot \frac{1}{k} \leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(a_k\right)^3 \right)^{1/3} \cdot \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^{3/2} \right)^{2/3}\ $ and let $n\to\infty.\ $ Is this correct?

Comment: I disagree with the closure. The last sentence of the post clearly shows the OP has given some non-trivial thought to the question.

Comment: What exactly in the link given by @jjagmath above on "how to ask a good question" was *not* done by the OP in the current question, that the people voting to close feel is critical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Clearly, $a_n$ should be sign-alternating.

Not quite. It needs to *change* signs (otherwise, it's a positive series wlog), but *alternating* is not necessarily the best way to get a counter-example.

Try the sequence given by
$$a_{3n-2} = a_{3n-1} = \frac{1}{(\log(n+1))^{1/3}}, \qquad a_{3n} = -\left(\frac{2}{\log(n+1)}\right)^{1/3} \tag{1}$$
for all $n\geq 1$. Since $a_{3n-2}^3 + a_{3n-1}^3 + a_{3n}^3 = 0$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^3=0$, the series $\sum_n a_n^3$ converges.

Note however then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{3N} \frac{a_n}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{(3n-2)\log^{1/3}(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(3n-1)\log^{1/3}(n+1)} - \frac{2^{1/3}}{3n\cdot \log^{1/3}(n+1)} \right) \tag{2}
$$
and since
$$
\frac{1}{(3n-2)\log^{1/3}(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(3n-1)\log^{1/3}(n+1)} - \frac{2^{1/3}}{3n\cdot \log^{1/3}(n+1)} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{2-2^{1/3}}{3n\log^{1/3} n}
$$
by comparison (2) diverges.

Comment: (I believe the derivation in the second part is correct, but worth double-checking my asymptotics. Also, try replacing the $\log(n+1)$ by something else, see how that goes: any function growing too fast there will not be a coutnerexample...)

Comment: You forgot the cubic root in the term $\frac{2^{1/3}}{3n\cdot \log(n+1)}$

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks! should be better now.